# Building Python add-in button to calculate elevation change

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I'm building a python add in button that calculates elevation change. I want the user to be able to click the button, click one cell on a DEM, click another cell, and then display a message that has the calculated elevation change between the two cells. Below is my code. When I install it and click on the newly created button in ArcMap nothing happens. My cursor doesn't even change to the one I selected.

Can anyone tell me what my code is missing?

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class CollectElevations(object):
    """Implementation for ElevationDifference_addin.CollectElevations 
(Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = True
        self.shape="None"
        global clickCount
        self.cursor=3
        clickCount=0

    def onMouseDownMap(self,x,y,button,shift):
        global clickCount
        rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

        if clickCount==0:
            for raster in rasters:
                self.result=arcpy.GetCellValue_management(raster, "{} {}".format(x, y), "1").getOutput(0)
                clickCount=1

        elif clickCount==1:
            for raster in rasters:
                self.result2=arcpy.GetCellValue_management(raster, "{} {}".format(x, y), "1").getOutput(0)
                message = "Elevation difference is"+str(" ")+str(self.result-self.result2)
                pythonaddins.MessageBox(message, "Results:")
                clickCount=0
```

Comment: Have you created this as a button or as a tool? Buttons do *something* when they're clicked on and then stop when they reach the end of the code, tools *stay active* while still the current tool. Buttons, by nature, don't have onMouse... events because they hold focus until they end. BTW you haven't set the workspace for ListRasters but I think you would want to use arcpy.mapping.ListLayers instead and filter where the layer type is a raster layer (layer.isRasterLayer).

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work. Here's the solution for anyone curious.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ElevationDifference(object):
    """Implementation for ElevationDifferenceFinder_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"
        self.cursor=3
        global clickCount
        global result
        clickCount=0

    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):

        global clickCount
        global result

        raster = pythonaddins.GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame()

        if not raster:
            mess="You must first select the DEM in the Table of Contents"
            pythonaddins.MessageBox(mess,"Warning:")

            return

        if clickCount==0:

            value=arcpy.GetCellValue_management(raster, "{} {}".format(x, y), "1")
            result=value.getOutput(0)
            print "Result 1 is {}".format(result)

            clickCount=1

        elif clickCount==1:

            result2=arcpy.GetCellValue_management(raster, "{} {}".format(x, y), "1").getOutput(0)
            print "Result 2 is {}".format(result2)


            finalresult=float(result)-float(result2)

            message = "Elevation difference is "+str(finalresult)
            pythonaddins.MessageBox(message, "Results:")

            clickCount=0
            result=0
```

Comment: raster should be a layer or data frame, I would suggest testing this object in three steps if type(raster) is arcpy.mapping.Layer: if not raster.isBroken: if raster.isRasterLayer: before trying to GetCellValue with it.